# Spring boot Application Failed to Start in Linux

Tags: spring-boot

Spring boot project can be run in local eclipse and windows environment use -jar. However , in the Linux environment, here are some problems to cause the Application Failed to Start. But the Process is always Running.

Spring Version is 1.5.19 , this is multiple modules project , logs in the Linux server is :

```
The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [CleanCursors-2-thread-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 28081 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured.

Action:

Verify the connector's configuration, identify and stop any process that's listening on port 28081, or configure this application to listen on another port.
```

I'm sure the port has not been occupied by any other processes. It make me confused that in the local environment , everything is Ok.

Some code in Pom.xml

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <!--exclusions slf4j-log4j12-->
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring db template -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring db template -->
        <!-- ${environments.${env}.sslPWD} related -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.18</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- ${environments.${env}.sslPWD} related -->
        <!-- Spring boot security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring boot security -->
        <!-- Monitor Spring boot app -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Monitor Spring boot app -->
```

Hope Linux server no errors.

Comment: There is no reason for spring boot to complain that port `28081` is being used if it is not. Try changing the port number in the properties file: `server.port` to another value to see if you are getting the same error.

Comment: @Prashant I have tried to change another port : 28089 , here is the same error , The Tomcat connector configured to listen on port 28089 failed to start. The port may already be in use or the connector may be misconfigured. And I use the netstat to check port 28089 . Here is only one process:tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:28089               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      22330/java

Comment: I think your application is trying to start twice.

Comment: Please post the entire log.

Comment: Thank you all ! I have fixed this problem that I found I set wrong key store and trust store location in the application.properties. It can't find the stores in server so can not start tomcat server.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem today, turns out i had one springboot docker container that i forgot about and it was still running and it was blocking the port in which Tomcat would start.

please run the following commands in your terminal:

`sudo ss -tulpn | grep LISTEN`

Also, install lsof and run: `lsof -i :28081` to see if any process is listening on the port.

Comment: I use the command : netstat -anp | grep 28081 to check the process. And here is only one process : tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:28089               0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      22330/java . This is the spring boot project's process. And here is still this problem.

Answer (score 0):

For my question , I found I set wrong location of key store and trust store, it can not find stores in the linux server. When I changed to the right location, everything is OK.
Application.properties

```
server.ssl.key-store=/opt/PFTestServices/etc/SSL-keystore.jks
server.ssl.trust-sotre=/opt/PFTestServices/etc/certs/SSLTrust.jks
```

Thanks a lot for help about this question !